# Android: Change Fragment within a ViewPager without Sliding

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager

i am a beginner so please keep that in mind when answering.

I just implemented the functionality to slide between 2 different Fragments. I followed this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

It is working fine. But i also want to give the option to switch between those 2 Fragments by clicking a Button instead of swiping the screen.

```
public void timerWindowButton(View v) {
    //timerWindow() executes the newInstance() method of the fragment
    Fragment fragment = timerWindow();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    //here i try to replace the content of the pager, but the result is 
    //an empty screen
    ft.replace(R.id.pager, fragment);
    ft.commit();
```

I tried to google my problem, but i just end up with search results for how to implement a ViewPager in the first place.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Try to use viewPager.setCurrentItem(1); inside your button click listener.
Make sure you load your fragments properly before showing them up.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly!

Comment: Great !!! Happy coding..

Comment: Do you wanna post that as a "real" answer? Wouldnt that be better for you and for future readers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use viewPager.setCurrentItem(1); inside your button click listener. Make sure you load your fragments properly before showing them up.